# Unity 3D Sistema de Puertas(cambio de escenas) C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Unity y he llegado a una duda. Os pongo en situación: Hay un poblado con distintas casas, el personaje puede acceder a esas casas por la puerta, se acerca a ella, colisiona con un `Trigger` y presiona  una tecla y entra al interior  de la casa, cargando una nueva escena.

Cuando el jugador quiere salir del interior de la casa se acerca a la puerta que contiene otro `trigger` y presiona una tecla, carga de nuevo la escena y aparece en el poblado.

Aquí viene mi duda, ya que no consigo que se ponga delante de la puerta, siempre acaba estableciendo la posición que tiene por defecto al cargar la escena. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer? El nombre de la escena y las coordenadas en las que quiero que el personaje aparezca se las asigno desde el propio Unity.

El código que tengo hecho es el siguiente:

```
public bool trigger;
public string escenaFinal; //nombre de la escena
public Vector3 coord;

void Start(){

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.tag == "Player") {

        trigger = true;    //Trigger true

        }
    }

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){

    if (other.tag == "Player") { //Sale del trigger falso

        trigger = false;

    }
}

void Update(){

}

void OnGUI(){
    if (trigger) {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 60, 200, 25), "Presiona K"); //Estamos en trigger
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K)){ //Si está dentro del Trigger y pulsa la letra K
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position = coord;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(escenaFinal); //Cargamos la escena
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position = coord;
        }
    }
}
```

La parte de `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position = coord;` es donde debería establecer la posición asignada pero no lo hace. Gracias y espero vuestras respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema me surgio a mi, lo que hice fue usar el PlayerPreferences que tiene unity 3D, en un script global, cargas el PlayerPreferences, y cuando entras en una casa, guardas la posicion x,y,z de la puerta de entrada, y al salir, lo primero que haces es verificar esas coordenadas para mover el personaje hasta alli una vez carga la escena.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        //Así guardas las coordenadas
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_x", 10.3f);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_y", 54.03f);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_z", 0f);
    }

    void salirDeCasa(){
        //Así recoges los valores
        float x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_x", 0);
        float y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_y", 0);
        float z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ultimacasavisitada_z", 0);

        //Creamos un Vector3 y movemos al personaje instantaneamente a esa coordenada
    }
}
```

Te dejo el enlace a la docu para mas info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: No termino de entender como hacerlo, ¿hay algún vídeo o algo por YouTube de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Busca por youtube como usar el playerprefs, no se si habrá algo al respecto (en español), basicamente lo que tienes que hacer es un cambio de escena cuando entras y sales de una casa, pues antes de entrar tienes que guardar las coordenadas de la puerta en el playerprefs (que es una variable que no se borra al cambiar de escena), y al salir de una casa leerla, no tiene mayor complicación.

Answer (score 0):

la linea

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").transform.position
```

retorna un arreglo de objetos con todos los tags player que encuentra,si es el unico tag player que tienes intenta con esto

```
GameObject player=GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
player.transform.position=coord;
```